# What is the reasoning in this step of proving classification of finite abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I'm studying classification of finite abelian groups. The proof I'm reading can be found [here](http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf).

I am trying to understand the proof of the second lemma in this file, but I'm stuck at the following part:

> But $G / K = (C + K) / K \oplus H / K$ means that $G = (C +K) + H = \ldots$

So I am wondering why this is true.

---

Edit: one commenter suggessted I add definitions for the folowing symbols:

$C = A \oplus B$ means direct sum of two groups (every element from C can be written as $c = a + b$ while also $A \cap B = \{ 0 \}$ )

$C = A + B$ means sum of two groups (every element from C can be written as $c = a + b$)

Comment: This could do with being more self-contained. Please [edit] to include more details.

Comment: @Shaun I'm not sure what I should edit?

Comment: The difference between $+$ and $\oplus$, for example, and what $G, C, K,$ and $H$ are relative to each other.

Comment: @Shaun do you mean I should copy paste the lemma and proof to the question?

Comment: No, not copy & paste; more like put them into your own words. At least you should define things, as stated in my comment above.

Comment: @Shaun I edited the question, is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, that's better. Thank you.

Comment: If I am reading it correctly, I think it is the following. Suppose $G/K = (C+K)/K \oplus H/K$. Let $g \in G$. We see that there is an $x \in C+K$ and a $y \in H$ so that $g + K = (x + K) + (y + K) = x + y + K$. So there exists $k_1, k_2 \in K$ so that $g + k_1 = x + y + k_2$, or $g = x + y + (k_2 - k_1)$. Since $G$ is abelian, rearrange it to get that $g \in C + K + H$.

Comment: Thank you @User203940 !

Comment: Regarding definitions, my advice is: first copy and paste them into your brain. Then you can copy and paste them from your brain to any other medium you want.